# How to set OneToOneField to empty / blank / null?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a simple OneToOneField set up:

```
class MyRelatedModel(models.Model):
    pass

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = OneToOneField(MyRelatedModel, blank=True, null=True)

>>> my_related_instance = MyRelatedModel()
>>> my_related_instance.save()

>>> my_model_instance = MyModel(my_field=my_related_instance)
>>> my_model_instance.save()
```

This means that I can access `my_related_instance` via `my_model_instance.my_field`.
However, I want to break this association:

```
>>> my_model_instance.my_field = None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'myrelatedmodel_id'

>>> setattr(my_model_instance, 'my_field', None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'myrelatedmodel_id'
```

I know that I *could* delete the associated `my_related_instance`, but in this case I just want to break the association. As you can see, both `blank` and `null` are set to `True`.

How do I set the `OneToOneField` to empty / blank / null?

*For reference, I am using django 1.4.*

Comment: the logic just sounds wrong. it would be interesting to hear some details about what you are about to accomplish. maybe there is a better solution

Comment: It may sound wrong, but I don't understand how a one-to-one relationship can be established, but not abolished.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your models you can ask django not to build a backward relation.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ForeignKey(MyRelatedModel, related_name='+')
```